# The application has stopped unexpectedly: How to Debug for flash builder

Tags: apache-flex

I need to use the mobile debug mode but every time I run the debug mode. The flex installed a app on my phone and then my phone show up "the application has stopped." messeage. The flex jump out form the debug mode and I cannot even open the installed app. The application dont even have dataservice attach to it or any UIobject on it expect the basic one. Any reason??

My code is very simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160">
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Bidding" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.BiddingView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Reuse" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.ReuseView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Account" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.AccountView"/>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

just like this.

the code of the view is like this all three of them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Account">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:View>
```

And I am using Flex 4.6 and This app is developed for Android.

Comment: More info needed.  Are you testing on iOS or Android or Playbook?  Has Flash Builder stopped execution at a breakpoint?  What is your code?

Comment: And I haven't done anything to the application yet, even adding a break point.

Comment: Actually I can find the app, but, even without debug mod, I cannt open it.

Comment: Are you testing on iOS or Android or Playbook? Where is the code for your views? Also, which version of Flex are you using?

Comment: And I am using Android and Flex 4.6